# Python auto completion in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, autocomplete, intellisense

I have a trouble in Python auto completion in Visual Studio 2015 (not VS Code).

When I use another library(?) such as tensorflow, 
tensorflow's functions and variables are helped by Visual Studio's intellisense and work well.

But Python's basic functions are not helped by intellisense (e.g. `print()`, `import`). When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is pressed they show up, but not automatically. So I always have to type `print()` fully or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> all time.

I really want to make them (e.g. `print()`, `import`, `def`) shown up automatically.

Comment: Hi k song, I tested it on my VS 2015 and got the same result as yours, it looks like by designed. You can try to use the VS 2017 and the basic functions are works fine and I tried it on my side, since there have some improvement for python intellisense from VS 2015 to VS 2017, please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/code-editing

Comment: hi tamura. thank you for reply. I'll try it